# Could not find phonepe.intentsdk.android.release:IntentSDK:2.4.1 React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, node.js, react-native

android build gradle :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-      projects/modules.

 buildscript {
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 33
    targetSdkVersion = 33

    // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
    ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
  }
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    // phonepe step 1
    maven {
        url  "https://phonepe.mycloudrepo.io/public/repositories/phonepe-intentsdk-android"
   }
   
 }
  dependencies {
    classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
    classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
    classpath ("com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0")
  }
 }



 app gradle :

  apply plugin: "com.android.application"
  apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


 dependencies {
 // phonepe step 3
 implementation("phonepe.intentsdk.android.release:IntentSDK:2.4.1")


 // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
 implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
 // react native camera
 // implementation 'com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:17.2.0'
 implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.3.1')
 implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")

 debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
 debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
    exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
 }

debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
    implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
} else {
    implementation jscFlavor
}
```

}

i am trying to integrate phone pe payment gateway sdk using official doc https://developer.phonepe.com/v1/docs/android-pg-sdk-integration but my project get build failled

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find phonepe.intentsdk.android.release:IntentSDK:2.4.1.
> Required by:
> project :app

Answer (score 0):

The following code needs to be added outside the 'buildscript' block:

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
       maven {
            url  "https://phonepe.mycloudrepo.io/public/repositories/phonepe-intentsdk-android"
       }
   }
}
```

So, your android build gradle looks something like this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-      projects/modules.

buildscript {
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 33
    targetSdkVersion = 33

    // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
    ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
  }
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral() 
 }
  dependencies {
    classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
    classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
    classpath ("com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0")
  }
 }

allprojects {
   repositories {
       maven {
            url  "https://phonepe.mycloudrepo.io/public/repositories/phonepe-intentsdk-android"
       }
   }
}
```

refer to this [link](https://github.com/PhonePe/pg-sdk-react-native-sample/blob/main/android/build.gradle) for proper placement during PhonePe SDK integration."